# getting error while programming star tsp650 in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When I add the starIO.framework and try to run my application it says that `#include <starmicronics/Platform.h` could not be found. I checked the framework to confirm that the file was there and it was  dont know why I am getting this error. I even tried to download the framework again and install it again. However it is still coming out to could not be found .

Answer (score 0):

The starmicronics/Platform.h is inside the StarIO.framework..
You have to use #import